# Graphviz hierarchical graph with dependencies

Tags: graph, filesystems, graphviz

I'm trying to use Graphviz to generate a graph of a file system. The output should look something like this:

[image: Example]

Circle shaped vertices are directories and square shaped vertices are files. Black colored edges represent the hierarchical relation between file system elements. Red colored edges represent a dependency relation from one file to another. Both types of edges are directed.

I have found examples on [www.graphviz.org](http://www.graphvis.org) for creating hierarchical graphs, but they only include the hierarchical relation. Can this be implemented with Graphviz? If not, is there some other software I can use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure thing, here you go.  I don't know how you'll detect the dependency relationships, but assuming your have a method, the simple coloration attributes as show will highlight them well.  Likewise, determining if something is a file or a directory is easy, so shape choice is easy too.

I've written the code in the order I imagine it would be discovered if you were drilling down from directory A but really the ordering of nodes, edges and subgraphs won't matter.

```
digraph X {
ranksep=.5
nodesep=.75

A [shape=circle]
{rank=same A}
A -> B
A -> C 

B [shape=circle]
C [shape=square]
{rank=same; B C}
B -> D
B -> E

D [shape=square]
E [shape=square]
{rank=same D E}
D -> E [color=red]
C -> E [color=red]
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it is just what I wanted :)